# Would a object member (or list of object member) not create a circular reference when using an ORM?

Tags: c#, orm

Please see the code below, which I am using to explain my question:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person p1 = new Person();
            List<Sport> sports = new List<Sport>();
            Sport sport = new Sport();
            sport.description = "Football";
        }

        public class Person
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public IList<Sport> sports { get; set; }

            public Person()
            {
                sports = new List<Sport>();
            }

        }

        public class Sport
        {
            public string description { get; set; }
            public IList<Person> person { get; set; }

            public Sport()
            {
                person = new List<Person>();
            }
        }
    }
```

The code shows that a Person plays many Sports and a Sport has many participants (people).  In the main method I create an instance of Person and add items to a collection (sports).

Say I had Person and Sports in a database and initialised Person using an ORM like Entity Framework or NHibernate.  Would this not create a circular reference.  Here is what I see happening:

```
1) A Person is loaded into memory.  Person.Sports is initialised with values.

2) Person.Sports.Person is initialised with values

3) Person.Sports.People.Sports is initialised with values

4) Person.Sports.People.Sports.People is initialised with values

5) and so on
```

How does an ORM deal with this? I have spent a few hours investigating this without fully understanding it and hence the reason for the question.

Comment: One approach an ORM could take would be to lazy-load the properties.  So they *are* circular references, but don't result in an infinite recursion unless the code you write requests one.  One common example of that would be attempting to serialize the object, where the serialization library doesn't expect to have to deal with an infinite recursion even though the ORM handles it just fine.

Comment: @David, thanks.  I don't see an issue with lazy loading (as the properties are only loaded if and when they are needed).  However, what about eager loading?

Comment: In that case I imagine some configuration of the ORM tool would be required.  Either through explicit configuration or through convention in the class design.  Ultimately the relationship itself is a standard many-to-many.  So any ORM would encounter that exact problem pretty early in development.  If the solution is configuration then even in an eager-loaded system the ORM would be told not to over-eagerly load these particular properties, and to perhaps only load one iteration.